# Video and other multimedia locks up and crashes Epiphany browser

Tags: epiphany

I love the Epiphany browser's look and aesthetic, but when using pages with a lot of multimedia content, it will eventually lock up, or crash. I already have gstreamer1.0-libav installed. I'm currently using Firefox, but would like to be able to use the default browser, but it currently has too many issues. Youtube plays fine, but other sites, like Musecore.org tutorials, and my school's website don't work properly.

Comment: Same here, tried Epiphany on both elementary os juno and ubuntu 18.04 and if the website has a few flash video plugins on one and the same page once you start one of them when you try to start another one the browser freezes until you close it and start it again.. Even closing it after such a freeze takes a lot of time in a really good computer.. I think this is a bug of the browser..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's crashing, then you should file a bug report [with a quality backtrace](https://wiki.gnome.org/Community/GettingInTouch/Bugzilla/GettingTraces) so it can be investigated. Crash reports are much appreciated as long as they contain a good backtrace. Nobody can assist with your crash otherwise.

As for the hangs... unfortunately [that is a known issue](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=197558). It will be half-fixed in the forthcoming WebKitGTK 2.24.4 release, but [the other half of the fix](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-bad/merge_requests/427) will not be available until GStreamer 1.16.1 at the earliest (and maybe not even until GStreamer 1.18, it's still uncertain). Since elementary OS will almost certainly not update GStreamer past the version available from Ubuntu, than means it will unfortunately remain broken until the next major version of elementary OS.

The only good news here is the next OS version should include Epiphany as a flatpak instead of a deb package, so important fixes should land much more quickly.

Edit October 2019: The fix is available in GStreamer 1.16.1.

Comment: Thanks I'll see if I can generate a backtrace when I get a chance